# How can I extract each dict from a list and put it into dataframe?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list like this:
`['{"a":0,"b":1,"c":2},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}']`

It only has one item on the list.
I would like to extract each dictionary and put them into one Dataframe.

Comment: Yes, your list contains one item, which is a string. Why is this surprising? Do you see the `'` marks on either side?

Comment: are you aware that there are single quotes right after the opening bracket and right before the closing bracket of the list? which doesn't make this a list of dictionaries but a list with one element, which is a string that looks like three dictionaries?

Comment: Anyway, it isn't possible to help you with this because it isn't clear what you want to happen. There are any number of ways you could put multiple dictionaries into a Dataframe. Please show what you want the Dataframe to look like, for this input. Also, please be aware that Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service; you are expected to make an attempt yourself first. Please read [ask].

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like `df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(f'[{l[0]}]'))`?

Comment: Thanks! @Nick,  This is exactly what I need.

Comment: Hi, @karl-knechtel, thanks for your comments. Probably my statement was a bit ambiguous. I wanted to convert the weird list to a data frame.  I just tried Nick's answer, which works perfectly!

Comment: Yes, I understand that you want to "convert the weird list to a data frame". The question is, *which dataframe*? There are many different things the result could contain, that are all things you might want to end up with from that list.

Answer (score 0):

use loads from the json module to make this a real list of dictionaries.
then just pass it to DataFrame():

```
from json import loads
from pandas import DataFrame

weird_list = ['{"a":0,"b":1,"c":2},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}']

real_list = loads(f"[{weird_list[0]}]")
```

then either pass the whole list to DataFrame if you want them in one place

```
three_dct_df = DataFrame(real_list)
three_dct_df
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  1  2  3
2  1  2  3
```

or loop over it creating individual DataFrames.
But if using scalar values you have to pass an index so ..

```
for lst in real_lst:
    print(DataFrame(lst, index= [0]))

   a  b  c
0  0  1  2

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3

   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
```